# Can I use bell switch with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: switches

I'm building a thing and I wanna use some nice looking buttons in it. I found some bell switches [like this](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01MY6T06H/ref=ox_sc_mini_detail?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A2RT9IRMJITYMY) that look pretty nice. The question is, do these work like normal switches with my Raspberry Pi?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please explain how that differs from any other push button switch electrically

Comment: @jsotola if I knew, I wouldn't ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any electrical switch will work with the raspberry pi, it doesn't matter what it looks like... so yes, those will work just like any other switch. just insert two jumper wires into the terminals at the bottom, screw them tight, then plug the jumper wires into whatever pin your using on your raspberry pi!